# Last Modified date in URL

Tags: java, url

I'm writing client socket code in java and I found this piece of code which is supposed to read a line and check last modified date.

I am confused why does it need to subtract the length by 21 in the modDateArr?

And is there any other way to do this?

```
while((x = br.readLine()) != null){
    if(x.contains("Last-Modified:")){
        modDateArr = new char[x.length()-21];
        x.getChars(20, x.length()-1, modDateArr, 0);
         // create mod date string from last mod info
        modDate = new String(modDateArr);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code example properly.

Comment: sorry for that but I am not used to the structure of the website when I post sth

Comment: Look for the "Edit" link or button to edit your question. Please fix your sample code. Look at other Questions or Answers to see correct formatting. Easy to do properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a better way: use `URL` and `URLConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://blablah/foo");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
Date lastModified = new Date(connection.getLastModified());
```

Note that the `Last-Modified` header looks like this:

```
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT
```

If you remove the first 21 characters from that line like your code does, you get this: `15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT`.